# used a call or made a call

Tags: usage

What is the meaning of **used a call** in the following sentence

> The President of the European Council **used a call** with Iran’s President Hassan Rouhani to call for a de-escalation of tensions after Tehran carried out missile strikes on U.S. military bases in Iraq in retaliation for the assassination of one of its top Generals.

[**Link**](https://www.thehindu.com/news/international/eu-council-chief-defends-iran-deal-after-trump-call-to-quit-it/article30526520.ece?utm_source=udmprecommendation_tamil-nadu&utm_medium=sticky_footer&transactionId=180d240455fd4d20a1b4dd33cd6f3007)

Is it correct to use **used a call**, I think it should be **made a call**

Comment: He _made a call_ to the President and _used_ it to ask for a de-escalation of tensions. In other words, the request was the purpose of the call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sentence is saying that he *used* the call (ie used the *opportunity*) to ask for something specific - to "call" (ask) for de-escelation.

World leaders often have scheduled calls with others. This *may* have been one of those occasions, so the call may not have been "made" in the usual sense of the word. Even if it was, he could stil have "used" it for a specific purpose.